# sql-Select rows with same id but different value in another column

Tags: mysql

Input:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | B |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | A |
| 5 | A |
| 5 | B |
| 6 | A |

Output

| ColumnA |
| --- |
| 4 |
| 6. |

for columnA for every first of  values is A, i need to fetch columnA those values have only A not in B,C

Comment: I really don't get your requirement frankly speaking. The only thing 4 and 6 have in common is that they have the same value for B and that they appear only once in A. But this is completely different of what you asked in the title.

Comment: Are you familiar with [`EXISTS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html)clause? If not, follow the link I provided,

Comment: @maio290 - perhaps you should vote to close it.

Comment: @RohitGupta A new user, probably whose native language isn't English. We don't need to be that prim, do we? We all make mistakes, so I guess it's more than appropriate to give people the possibility to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery with `NOT EXISTS` to exclude column A values that have matching rows with the disallowed values in column B.

```
SELECT columnA
FROM yourTable AS t1
WHERE columnB = 'A'
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM yourTable AS t2
    WHERE t1.columnA = t2.columnA
        AND t2.columnB IN ('B', 'C')
)
```